# Cannot connect to Firebase authentication (nothing happen)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I build some authentication app including input username, password on firebase. But nothing happen after i press on Log in button on my application. It only shows "Authentication Failed".

```
    class LoginForm extends Component {
      state = {
        email: '',password: '',error: '',loading: false
      };

      onButtonPress() {
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
          .catch(() => {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
              .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
              .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this));
          });
      }

      onLoginFail() {
        this.setState({ error: 'Authentication Failed.', loading: false });
      }

      onLoginSuccess() {
        this.setState({
          email: '',password: '',error: '',loading: false});
      }
     render
            ....
                value={this.state.email}
                onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
              />
            </CardSection>
            <CardSection>
              <Input
                ...
                onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
              />
```

Comment: You can debug this by passing an error through your catch block, like `catch(error => {console.log(error);}` - and let us know what the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to catch the error and console.log it.

```
 onButtonPress() {
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
          .catch((error) => { <===
            console.log(error); <===
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
              .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
              .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this));
          });
      }
```